# Prolog - How should I access a list of pairs?

Tags: prolog

How do I access a list with pairs in Prolog?

for example: `List[(x1,x2),(x3,x4),(x5,x6)]`

How do I access `x1 ? (x1,x2)` is the head of the list? So what is x1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Unification. Just provide the 'variables' for them, and they'll match up.

For instance, if you have a list of pairs that you want printed:

```
print_all_pairs([]).
print_all_pairs([(X, Y)|T]) :-
    write('Property '), write(X), write(' has a value of '), write(Y), nl,
    print_all_pairs(T).
```

Answer (score 3):

Prolog uses pattern matching. You can use the anonymous variable to unify with parts you do not need.

```
first([(X,_)|_], X).

?- first([(a,1),(b,2)], X).
X = a.
```

Answer (score 0):

To access any list item - not just the first, you can just use member/2 or memberchk/2:

```
?- List=[(x1,x2),(x3,x4),(x5,x6)], member((x3, XN), List).
List = [ (x1, x2), (x3, x4), (x5, x6)],
XN = x4 .
```

In the member/2 clause, x3 could also obviously be a variable, not hardwired.